# FreeTDS and MSServer Instance

Tags: linux, t-sql, freetds

I've been using FreeTDS to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server for some time now and it's been working well with the following configuration:

```
[mydb]
  host = 192.168.0.21
  port = 1434
  database = master
  tds version = 8.0

# tsql -S mydb -U user -P password  -D master
locale is "en_GB.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Default database being set to master
1> select @@version
2> go

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (Intel X86)
    Dec 28 2012 19:06:41
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)

(1 row affected)
1> exit
```

Since my production MS Server has multiple instances, I now have to connect to the database using instance instead of port. I tried this with the following configuration:

```
[mydb]
  host = 192.168.0.21
  instance = MYINSTANCE
  database = master
  tds version = 8.0
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
# tsql -S mydb -U user -P password -D master
locale is "en_GB.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Default database being set to master
16There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I did a strace on the command and got the following messages:

```
# strace -S mydb -U user -P password -D master
...
ioctl(3, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 1)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 2)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 3)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 4)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 5)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 6)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 7)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 8)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
 9)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
10)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
11)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
12)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
13)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
14)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
15)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
sendto(3, "\4MYDB\0", 6, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1434), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.21")}, 16) = 6
16)  = 0 (Timeout)s=POLLIN}], 1, 1000
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0x11ee000)                          = 0x11ee000
brk(0x11d6000)                          = 0x11d6000
write(2, "There was a problem connecting t"..., 45There was a problem connecting to the server
) = 45
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Does anyone know what could be happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Multiple instances of SQL Server each have their own port.  Port 1434 is the default port but only 1 instance can use this port.  Other instances must use a different port.  I suggest you determine the port that your instance is running on and try that in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My issue is that the production server is configured to use dynamic TCP ports. So I can't really rely on the port configuration here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've been using SQL Server for many years now.  In all that time, I have never known the port number to change unless someone manually changes it.  In my opinion, it is completely safe to use the port number.  Without the port number, you need to make sure that the SQL Browser service is started on the SQL Server computer and also allow UDP port 1433 (which is used by the SQL browser service).

Comment: I ended up using the generated port number for the server, but I find it strange that I was not able to connect using the instance configuration, specially considering the weird output above. Thanks for the help anyway.